# Where can you find the Gamma Gun and the Atom Cats?

Tags: fallout-4

I've searched almost everywhere but I can't find them.

Comment: Could you 1) Split your question into two questions and 2) Where have you tried?

Answer (score 4):

The [Decayed Reactor Site's](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Decayed_reactor_site) southern dome contains a dead Child of Atom cultist with a Gamma Gun.

I did some searching, but as far as I can tell, the "wild cats guys" aren't a thing in Fallout 4. Did you mean the Atom Cats? They can be found at the [Atom Cats Garage](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Atom_Cats_garage?file=Atom%20Cats%20garage%20map.png).

Comment: There's a map at that link, but just to include the information on this page: the Atom Cats Garage is a ways south and a little west of The Castle. It's in one of the higher leveled areas in the game.

Answer (score 0):

The places to find gamma guns are mostly at spots where the radiation symbols are on the maps with exception to a few. These guns are deadly unless you have a hazmat suit or a good supply of rad-x. Atom cats are on a location east of diamond city and its symbol is of the junkyard symbols.

Answer (score 0):

I've got three or four gamma guns which were all scavenged from random encounters in the wastelands. I don't remember exactly but they probably came from encounters with Children of the Atom, which I've had happen in a few places where you often get gangs of NPCs spawning, such as the ruined building north of Mass Gravel & Sand, and the crashed plane near the General Atomic factory.

Answer (score -1):

I found mine at a raider camp not sure were but I killed several ants then a legendary Razer somthing came out no were   killed it and it gave me the gamma gun.